# StructureMap AddAllTypesOf doesn't register instances

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

I am trying to register all types of IRequestStrategy interface like this:

```
        Scan(o =>
        {
            o.AddAllTypesOf<IRequestStrategy>();
        });
```

I don't get any instances registered back when needed, but it works with normal registration:

```
    For<IRequestStrategy>().Use<OneRequestStrategy>();
    For<IRequestStrategy>().Use<TwoRequestStrategy>();
```

Did I forget something in scan?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with adding all together:

```
scan.TheCallingAssembly();
scan.AddAllTypesOf<IRequestStrategy>();
scan.WithDefaultConventions();
```

Still have an issues with abstract classes though.

Comment: Have you tried `scan.AssemblyContainingType<YourType>();` ?